# ESP8266 error message at 74880 baud

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I just unpacked my 2nd ESP8266 thinking the first one was just broken but I'm getting the same weird errors with this one too.

I have only tried to upload the Blink example, and I haven't connected any pins yet.

This is the output when I press RST at 74880 baud:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v614f7c32
~ld
```

Is this a problem with my PC? Do these ESP8266s not have an OS on them?

Comment: 74880 is unusual, and i just got one the other day where that was the case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error. It's just [the boot message](https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=896).

Answer (score -2):

is not problem your PC or ESP88256. You need to configure BAUD

Comment: Other baud rates just give me garbage. This is valid output.